# Что будет, когда вы во float зададите число 10^100

Tags: python

Задали такой вопрос на собеседовании я не смог ответить. Скажите что будет то

Comment: Ну, во-первых в синтаксисе Python ^ - это битовый XOR (исключающее "или"), и если числа по битам не будет пересекаться (как в данном случае), то числа просто сложатся, получится 110) Если имеется в виду возведение в степень - это другой вопрос)

Comment: Получится примерное значение числа *10^100*.

Answer (score 3):

Возможно я не прав, но вроде бы в Python [оператор](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_operators.htm) "^" - это битовый "[Исключающее ИЛИ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5_%C2%AB%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%C2%BB)". Если подразумевается операция возведения в степень - то это оператор "**". Возможно подразумевается запись числа с [плавающей точкой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9), 10e+100.

Рекомендую использовать [REPL](https://ru.hexlet.io/courses/python-setup-environment/lessons/repl/theory_unit) для улучшения понимания работы с языком.

[image: пример работы с REPL]

Кстати, если всё таки был вопрос по битовой операции, то действительно как было сказано в комментарии переменная станет целого типа и будет хранить значение 110

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Наверное, на собеседовании все-таки сказали как-то не так, как вы этот вопрос тут излагаете. Потому что ответ находиться практикой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Наверное все же под записью **10^100** понимается 10 в степени 100.

А смысл вопроса был проверить понимание того как Python работает с вещественными числами и какие есть границы.
Т.е. по идее вопрос был о том "влезет" такое большое число в переменную типа float или нет.

Если отвечать коротко - то влезет.

Если чуть длиньше, то ответ на этот вопрос может зависить от используемой платформы. И для проверки лучше использовать функцию **sys.float_info**

Например,

```py
import sys
sys.float_info
```

В моем случае выводит

```
sys.float_info(
  max=1.7976931348623157e+308,
  max_exp=1024,
  max_10_exp=308,
  min=2.2250738585072014e-308,
  min_exp=-1021,
  min_10_exp=-307,
  dig=15,
  mant_dig=53,
  epsilon=2.220446049250313e-16,
  radix=2,
  rounds=1 
)
```

В контексте данного вопроса интересно значение **max_10_exp** - это, грубо говоря, максимальное число нулей у числа, которое может храниться в float. Это 308, что больше чем 100. А значит 10 в степени 100 без проблем можно использовать как float в Python.

Answer (score 1):

#### Если под ^ имеется в виду побитовое исключающее или

Тут можно и в голове посчитать, не зря операцию еще называют сложением по модулю 2

100 ^ 10 =
64+32+4 ^ 8+2 = (совпадающих значащих разрядов нет, значит результат будет равен сложению)
64+32+4 + 8+2

итого, ответом будет

110.0

#### Если под ^ имеется в виду возведение в степень

Тут уже в голове посчитать вряд ли получится, да и результат может разниться от платформы к платформе.

Если для хранения float в системе используется [число двойной точности стандарта IEEE_754](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)

То наше число 10**100, имеющее двоичное представление

```
10010010010011010110100100101100101001100001101111100111010110000101100100111100  
00100110001001100111000001011111100111000101011001110010000001000111000100001000  
11010011111001010101010110010010000110000100010101000001011101000111100010000000  
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  
0000000000000
```

округляется до первых 53 битов (именно округляется, так что следующий за ними единичный бит учитывается)

```
10010010010011010110100100101100101001100001101111101000000000000000000000000000  
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  
0000000000000
```

Это число и будет в точности сохранено в переменной типа float

```py
>>> 0b10010010010011010110100100101100101001100001101111101 << 280 == int(float(10**100))
True
```

Answer (score -2):

правильный ответ получится тип флоат вот пруфы

```
>>> type(float(10^100))
<class 'float'>
>>> type(float(10**100))
<class 'float'>
```

но а по факту нужно знать на какой машине будет выполнен под тк в питоне есть какието ограничения от оперативы, типа с наибольшим числом